# Is it possible to send image to email using CKeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

I've been creating a page where I can send some info with an image to a yahoo account. I'm using CKeditor and php mail. Is there a way to do it?  Actually I've tried it and it works good but the image is blank only the border size of the image is visible. Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? Maybe we can debug why the image is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not embedding the images to the email, most likely your URL is wrong. Try post-processing the URLs to be absolute and not relative and that will fix your problem.